# Detecting an "unselect" event in a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has the [`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) method, which lets you execute a function when text is selected in a text area.

Unfortunately, there is no corresponding `.deselect()` method for executing a function when the user removes a selection.

How can I detect when the user has unselected the text (for example, by typing, clicking, or defocusing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("textarea").select(function() {
    //do something here
});

$("textarea").on("blur focus keydown mousedown", function() {
    //do something else here
});​
```

[`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used in jquery 1.7 and later. Prior to that you can use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

http://jsfiddle.net/s29Vb/4/

It was simplified for the example. You can be more specific with the selector rather than `$("textarea")`.

Another example if you want to do something on `blur focus keydown mousedown` only if text has been selected in the first place.

http://jsfiddle.net/s29Vb/5/

Comment: What if I press Ctrl key, the selection is still there, so possibly need to filter out all function/application/... keys